# Encoding newline in VB.NET for HMAC SHA1

Tags: vb.net, oauth, newline, hmac

I'm having a problem authenticating an API with OAuth. I can get it work fine in Python, but not in VB.Net. I realised the issue is that SHA1 algorithm is returning a different value in Python and VB.NET for the what I thought was the same message. This only seems to be the case when there is a newline character "\n" in the message (which there has to be for the API call). Using `Environment.NewLine` doesn't seem to help.

The code I'm using (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515164/visual-basic-2010-hmac-sha1)) is here, with the expected values I get from my Python program:

```
Public Sub Main()           
    ' Expect D/5B78PD9pFhmqZQi3eenPBy6ks=
    ' Get    D/5B78PD9pFhmqZQi3eenPBy6ks=
    console.writeline(getHash("a", "msg"))

    ' Expect yuuq6RwtwkoJ6n3PquGFx60MLas=
    ' Get    uv4AwQjvYeCTajhHw7EFtPlJfCE=
    console.writeline(getHash("a", "msg\n"))

    ' Expect yuuq6RwtwkoJ6n3PquGFx60MLas=       
    ' Get efRfAnmIN/C/YX/UPHVPFY5VjJg=
    console.writeline(getHash("a", "msg" + Environment.NewLine))

End Sub

Public Function getHash(ByVal key As String, ByVal msg As String) As String
    Dim myEncoder As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    Dim keyBytes() As Byte = myEncoder.GetBytes(key)
    Dim msgBytes() As Byte = myEncoder.GetBytes(msg)

    Dim myHMACSHA1 As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(keyBytes)
    Dim HashCode As Byte() = myHMACSHA1.ComputeHash(msgBytes)

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(HashCode)
End Function
```

In case it's useful, my Python program is:

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac

key = "a"
msg = "msg\n"
key_byte = key.encode('utf-8')
msg_byte = msg.encode('utf-8')

h = hmac.new(key_byte, msg_byte, hashlib.sha1)
print base64.b64encode(h.digest())   # yuuq6RwtwkoJ6n3PquGFx60MLas=
```

My guess is it's something to do with how the newline character is encoded, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with I'd just like to point out that `\n` in VB.NET does not represent a new line character. It will literally just become `\n`.

[**`Environment.NewLine`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) adapts to the current OS. Different operating systems use different line endings. The issue here is that the Python code is using a [**Line Feed**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character (`\n`) as a new line indicator, but since `Environment.NewLine` adapts to the OS it will return Windows' line ending, which is [**Carriage Return**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) + **Line Feed** (`\r\n`).

Therefore if you want it to match the Python code you've got to be sure to insert a Line Feed **only**. For instance:

```
Console.WriteLine(getHash("a", "msg" & vbLf))
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been trying. I've tried to use `vbLf ` and `Chr(10)` but it says they are not declared. I can't figure out which module they are hiding in.

Comment: @PeterCollingridge : They're somewhere in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace. Make sure your project references `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`.

Comment: I'm currently testing on an online interpreter (https://dotnetfiddle.net/). Maybe they are not available there for some reason. I can try in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ah, I see, I need `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic`. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterCollingridge : That's because you've got to import the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace on dotnetfiddle. It is auto-imported in Visual Studio. Try it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VAzv7h -- **EDIT:** Oh, you beat me to it. Glad I could help!